# Do we have to redo category theory when learning about enriched categories?

Tags: category-theory, big-picture, enriched-category-theory

I'd like to know whether there exists a common language that encompasses both categories and enriched categories, so that results pertaining to either may be proven in a uniform way. I'd prefer it if that common language were a generalisation of both categories and enriched categories that is as far-reaching as possible.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Well, I'd say that you first have to have a notion of monoidal category in order to do any enriching. That said, once you've defined enriched categories (using this notion) one can prove things for both enriched categories and ordinary categories at the same time by regarding ordinary categories as being $\mathbf{Set}$ enriched.

Comment: As for your second question, I think it's unclear what exactly you mean. That said, I think the answer is yes, but addressing all generalisations of ordinary categories is far too broad a question, and is not appropriate for MSE. Even asking what all the generalisations of ordinary categories are is probably too broad.

Comment: @jgon Could you point to a rule of this site that would support your claim? Please don't take offence - I'm simply insufficiently familiar with this site.

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous The first few points here https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and the Be Specific section of https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask as well as Too Broad close reason which states to "limit [the question] to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer" and to "avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once".

Comment: At the moment, I don't really see how my question might be to broad. I also don't think that it violates any of the points in the first link. Hence, I'd kindly ask you to put it back "off hold" and restore its status to normal. Thank you!

Comment: jgon already answered your question. Enriched category theory is a *generalization* of category theory, so this generalizes both enriched categories and $Set$-enriched (=traditional) categories. (You're basically asking for a 'common upper bound' of certain $A$ and $B$ where $A\le B$, then an obvious answer is $B$.)

Comment: Yet, the provided answer fails to give a path towards the definition of an enriched category that would not already use the definition of a category. And if the question has been answered, it would certainly be virtuous to indicate so to any who might find a link to this question (eg. by providing a community wiki answer).